# Find only single direction relation in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In my neo4j graph-db, I have one type of node `Person` and one type of relation `SENT_GIFT`. So this makes two way relation between two specific `Person`s. For example -

i) person_1 may only gift to person_2

ii) person_2 may only gift to person_1

iii) person_1 and person_2 can gift each other

Now I want to write a cypher that will find - all the persons who has given gift (SENT_GIFT) to a specific_person (specified by profileid), but the specific_person has not gifted to those persons.

I am trying to write the Cypher in below way -

```
MATCH (specific_person:Person {profileid: <profile_id>})
MATCH (from_person:Person)-[rOpp:SENT_GIFT]->(specific_person)-[rDir:SENT_GIFT]->(from_person)
WHERE rDir is null
RETURN from_person;
```

But not getting expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Match (user:User)-[r]->(user2:User)
Where Not (user2)-[]->(user)
Return user, r, user2
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use a WHERE clause here negating the pattern you don't want in the match.

Something like:

```
MATCH (from_person:Person)-[:SENT_GIFT]->(specific_person:Person {profileid: $profile_id})
WHERE NOT (specific_person)-[:SENT_GIFT]->(from_person)
RETURN from_person;
```